# Replacing values in Dataframe if its more than the mean of that column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

There are three columns in dataframe. what can be an optimized code in R which can first check for the value if it exceeds the mean of the particular variable and then replace it with the mean. 
P.S: Means of all three variables are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One basic option here is to use the `ifelse()` function to create new variables. For an optimized code, you can use the `data.table` package.

```
data <- mtcars[, 1:3]

library(data.table)
setDT(data)
# look at means
mean(data$mpg) #20.09062
mean(data$cyl) #6.1875
mean(data$disp) #230.7219

# new variables
data[, mpg_new := ifelse(mpg > mean(mpg), mean(mpg), mpg)]
data[, cyl_new := ifelse(cyl > mean(cyl), mean(cyl), cyl)]
data[, disp_new := ifelse(disp > mean(disp), mean(disp), disp)]
```

Comment: Thank you but I am actually looking for a For loop which checks values and replaces it with the mean of the specific variable.

Comment: I created new variables just in case you would like to use original variables. But if you want to replace them, this should also work: `data[, mpg := ifelse(mpg > mean(mpg), mean(mpg), mpg)]
data[, cyl := ifelse(cyl > mean(cyl), mean(cyl), cyl)]
data[, disp := ifelse(disp > mean(disp), mean(disp), disp)]`

Comment: I understand your approach but can we write a loop which iterate itself and replace the exceeding value with its mean?

Comment: Are you expected a different result than the one produced by the previous code? I believe that a For loop will create here a biased result since the mean will change at each iteration. Here is an example `for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data$mpg <- ifelse(data$mpg > mean(data$mpg), mean(data$mpg), data$mpg)
} `. Look at the result.

Comment: @BhaskarAbhishek could you try ANG's code to see if it provides the expected output? If it does not provide the output you expect, could you edit your original post to indicate the conditions you prefer (such as a for loop) and the output you expect?

Comment: @Ang 
> for(i in 1:ncol(mycars)){
  for(j in nrow(mycars)){ 
ifelse(mycars[j,i]>mean(mycars[,i]),mean(mycars[,i], na.rm=T),mycars[j,i])}}

I am trying something like the above code snippet. Unfortunately its not working

Comment: I would definitely _not_ use a for loop to iterate over the rows. Thats a terribly slow way to do this in R. Instead, you want to leverage R's strength in subsetting and vectorisation. In fact, for this you need neither the data.table package, nor the ifelse() function. Just do e.g. `data$mpg[data$mpg > mean(data$mpg)] <- mean(data$mpg)`. You could then wrap this vectorised expression in a for loop to iterate over column, and/or use integer subsetting